# Use a random variable to determine path in Google forms

Tags: forms

I have found Google Forms to be useful for quick surveys. However, I can't figure out how to create a random variable to control flow of a survey. I know I can go ahead and create a custom app but I was hoping that there was an easier way via the Google Form. So for example, I want to test 1/2 the people with question version A and 1/2 the people with question version B. So I want to call a random variable and then go to Page A flow or Page B flow. Does anyone know how to do this with Google forms?